# Am I allowed to use a students license for my Bachelor Thesis at work?

Tags: software, licensing, germany

I am doing a integrated degree program in Germany. As a student, I have free access for a variety of software programs. It is important that I may not use these for commercial purposes.

I am now working on my Bachelor Thesis and would like to use such a program. Part of the things I will be doing with it will be only for the theoretical sections of the Thesis. Other Parts will most likely be used commercially by my company later on. Am I allowed to use my personal student's license?

The [FAQ](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/#faq) on their website does not clarify this case. Their [License Terms](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/license_educational.html) state that I may not "use Products for any commercial purposes". The problem is that I am not sure, if this is a commercial purpose. I want to use the software "PyCharm".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use them for commercial purposes, now or later. That means you can put it in your thesis, but you can not later on use the same code for any commercial purposes.

That said, PyCharm has a community edition which is free and may be used for any purpose, just download and use this version.